# Fullcalendar create mutiple events based on the dates mentioned in the modal

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a modal which has two event dates how to create two events in fullcalendar when clicked on add button.I tried this.

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function (e) {
$('#interviewModal').modal('hide');
var arr = new Array();
var event = {
title : $('#txtTitle').val(),
start : $('#txtStartDate').val(),
end : $('#txtEndDate').val(),
allDay: false,
stick : true
}

var event2 = {
title : $('#txtTitle').val(),
start : $('#txtStartDate2').val(),
end : $('#txtEndDate2').val(),
allDay : false,
stick : true
}


arr.push(event);
arr.push(event2)

e.preventDefault();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',arr);
});

Also my modal looks like this
```

[Modal Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5BPT.png)

Comment: Have you checked with 'renderEvents' instead 'renderEvent' ?

Comment: @Pooja did you fix this? Did the answer help? If so please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use "renderEvents" instead of "renderEvent". https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvents/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', arr, true);
```

This accepts an array of events, instead of a single one.